# How to get com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3 from maven in android studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Today, I got an trouble when get library from maven and I can't download com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3 when I use gradle in android studio.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
```

I know this is old version but I still want to use it.
I tried to download from maven repository but not found the file

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.exoplayer/exoplayer/2.7.3

So I come here to ask a solution for that.

Thank you.

Comment: Some maven repositories were closed or disabled public access. It looks like that version isn't available anymore in one of the known repositories. You can try to use a slightly newer version or check the internet if you find it in a different (untrusted) repository.